# POCO websocket messes after 50 minutes of working

Tags: c++, qt, poco-libraries

I have the following question related to POCO library. My client listens the messages from our backend server using POCO library. All is well the first 50 minutes, then with the socket happens something strange and method "receiveFrame" begins to return an exception. After that, the socket does not become operational. I have made few tests the time after which I receive not operational socket is exactly 50 minutes. Also I need to note that our backend server doesn't send anything during all time. I have no idea what happens... Below is code of our Handshake and Read procedures:

```
void WebSocketManager::Handshake()
{
    qDebug() << "WebSocketManager::Handshake";

    try {
        HTTPResponse response;
        QString origin = Settings::Instance()->GetErPortal();
        QString host = origin.remove("http://");
        host = host.remove('/');
        QString token = "/event/bus/ws/subscribe?auth_token=" + Settings::Instance()->token().toUtf8();

        _wssession.setHost(host.toUtf8().constData());
        _wssession.setPort(80);

        HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, token.toUtf8().constData(),HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
        request.set("origin", origin.toUtf8().constData());

        _wssock = new WebSocket(_wssession, request, response);
        response.getStatus();

        HTTPResponse::HTTPStatus status = response.getStatus();
        qDebug() << "Handshake status is : " << status;

        if(status == HTTPResponse::HTTPStatus::HTTP_SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS)
            _status = true;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        qDebug() << "WebSocketManager::Handshake exception " << e.what();
    }
}

void WebSocketManager::Read()
{
    char receiveBuff[1024];

    while(_status)
    {

        qDebug() << "WebSocketManager::Read wait data...., thread = " << QThread::currentThread();

        try {
            int flags=0;
            int rlen=_wssock->receiveFrame(receiveBuff,1024,flags);

            if(!rlen)
            {
                qDebug() << "WebSocketManager::Read error";
                emit ConnectionFailed();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                qDebug() << "WebSocketManager::Read, len =" << rlen << ", flags = " << flags << ", data = " << receiveBuff;
                ProcessBackendEvent(QString(receiveBuff));
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception &e)
        {
            qDebug() << "WebSocketManager::Read exception " << e.what();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: To get a better idea of what exactly happens, catch Poco::WebSocketException& and log `displayText()`.

Comment: When it is happened I receive error 11. What do you mean talking about  displayText?

Comment: `try { ... } catch (Poco::WebSocketException& e) { qDebug() << e.displayText(); }`

Comment: I don't see any Poco::WebSocketException - I use now NetException. displayText produces same output as what() method.I use POCO library version 1.4.6

Comment: that's ancient. first thing I'd recommend is upgrade to 1.9.0 and see if it still happens - it is not yet clear to me that it is a poco problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is bug of POCO library described here https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/490
On 1.9.0 POCO library all work fine...